The consistent conflation of language?
Here's something I've been pondering about which I haven't been able to quite articulate well enough. The world is deterministic as it's just a sequence of events that reveals itself deterministically. There is no if in the physical world. Causality is actually a linguistic phenomena posited by  counterfactuals. If I did not push the cart it would not have moved.
Furthermore I realized statements like:

"Cause precedes effect"

is more of a conflation of language of science and the language of daily experience (of free will). The degree of freedom of science is the initial conditions where as from our experience the degree of freedom of  from our experience is our very actions. Then we look at time of our choice and posit cause precedes effect.
Consider the pushing the cart example.
Pushing the cart we are assuming the degree of freedom is our action of pushing it.
Then we draw a cutoff and now we now apply the laws of science where the degree of freedom as already be selected as the push.
How is it linguistically possible to consistently talk about causality from two different viewpoints? (what does it even mean for a language to be consistent?) Is this telling us something about language or the world?

I think it's telling you about which assertions you are presuming are baseline truths,  and that not everybody starts from that point.

There is no reason to assume that "natural language" is consistent. To be precise, consistency is not a property of languages but of collection of statements: theories. Our life is not governed by an overall theory.

Almost zero scientific explanations of anything draw everything back to "first causes" in some "beginning of time" sense.  We always start from some intermediate state and move forward from there: A cannon is fired at so-and-so angle and such a velocity, how many seconds does it take to fall?  No need to explain the origin of cannon or their composition in terms of protons and electrons.  In this sense "You push a cart" doesn't need an explanation of "you" in terms of protons, or "free will" or any other such thing.

I happen to think that almost the only way we ever speak about things is in implied conditionals. I.e. if I say "I have a cat," the only things that there are for me to mean are: "the universe is such that if one measures thus, one will feel soft furry texture, and if one measures thus one will measure hissing noises and painful scratching, etc etc"; or an arbitrary a priori metaphysical assertion of cat-having-ness upon which I shall base my entire ontology and epistemology and which no measurement could confirm or refute.

The reason we often apply the concept of free will to linguistics is because we have deluded ourselves into functioning with free will as a crucial component of life, whether it actually exists or not. Think about your childhood. Not to be presumptuous, but you were probably told as a child what you “should” and “should not” do presuming you have at least some autonomy. Think about how we speak. You often hear yourself say “why’d you do that?” or “I can’t believe you’d do that!” Which is how language has come to reflect our minds. We act in a way that assumes we have some autonomy. The legal system acts in the same way. Someone is either determined “guilty” or “not guilty” and a crucial factor in a punishment is your intention again assuming you have some autonomy.
“human moral equality flows from the human need to be the author of one’s own life.” - Danielle Allen, a political scientist. We see that we function on the basis of autonomy and that has been reflected in our language. Our language can’t be paradoxical because it’s simply a means of communication but the way we think is. We often see ourselves as the Main Character and perceive everything as it affects us and our senses. Therefore we caused the cart to move, that is a crucial factor in how we relate to the world and “if” is used to simply describe other possibilities allowed within the limits of of our mind. That’s how language is created and the reason slang exists is because as the generations go on our minds change and we adapt beliefs from other people which is reflected in our language.
Language is a reflection of the human mind that can be expressed to others. We can understand the world deterministically but we can’t escape our own mind, in a sense. So it’s possible for us to talk from 2 different view points as general language is a representation of the collective human body not a description of the world but a description of how we perceive the world. Hope that helps answer the question.


Consider the pushing the cart example. Pushing the cart we are assuming the degree of freedom is our action of pushing it.

I think for the most part, we aren't assuming "freedom of action", we are assuming that talking influences behaviour differently than if no talking occurred.
I actually can't think of many "daily" contexts in which any concept of "free will" is specifically invoked, unless you're talking to a philosopher.
Most "everyday" discourse actually proceeds on the basis that the will is not particularly free at all, but that each individual is engaged in a constant reckoning about their future action, whose outcome can be influenced by the prospect of reward, the threat of punishment, and by the structure of their conceptualisations and moral fabric. "Knowing" another person is often about knowing a relatively predictable profile of their behaviour.
And insofar as the individual is not responsive to these factors of influence, then their capacity to act can be destroyed (such as by bodily harm), or the reproduction of this non-responsiveness impaired.
The concept of "if" exists not because the physical world does go either way, but because our knowledge of it is underdetermined and we are capable of imagining and discussing more than one possibility.

Then we draw a cutoff and now we now apply the laws of science where the degree of freedom as already be selected as the push.

Yes, we largely make a distinction between analysing the physical world around us in a mechanical way, and participating in the ideological activity of a human community.
I wouldn't necessarily suggest this is because the two realms are irreconcilable, but because we have a special conceptualisation and vocabulary for participating in ideological activity which is non-general, but is nevertheless more efficient and well-adapted for its area of application.
It's also important to note that ideas generally don't have any intrinsic physical form (at least not one that seems accessible), or existence independent of the minds which host them. Therefore a physical description of ideas in terms of brain configurations and such, tends to have a fathomless complexity in practice, which is why the specialised approach remains distinct.
